# Jetpack Compose: "MeasuringIntrinsicsMeasureBlocks is not ready. layoutState is NeedsRelayout"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm receiving some crashes that I cannot relate to our own code, but it happens fairly often. It mostly seems to occur when the UI is updated rapidly, but I'm unable to reproduce it consistently.

I'm using

- Compose version 1.0.0-alpha10
- AGP version 7.0.0-alpha04

The stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: e@b4fb400 children: 4 measureBlocks: MeasuringIntrinsicsMeasureBlocks@34b1caf{ measureBlock=b.e.b.t.f$c@812b8bc } is not ready. layoutState is NeedsRelayout
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.java:94)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.java:34)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.java:9)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.java:34)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.java:9)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.java:60)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.java:34)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.java:9)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.java:60)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$2.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.java:4)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$2.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.java)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.java:62)
       at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.java:51)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.java:17)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.java:40)
       at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.java:2)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewLayer.dispatchDraw(ViewLayer.java:44)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21963)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20833)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5132)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5104)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20788)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5132)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5104)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20788)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5132)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5104)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20788)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5132)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5104)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20788)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5132)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5104)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20788)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5132)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5104)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20788)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5132)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:5104)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20788)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:725)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:731)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:840)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4035)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3798)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3100)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1963)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8719)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:988)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:765)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:700)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:967)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7266)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

What is going on here?

Comment: The only search result leads to https://github.com/android/compose-samples/issues/129, which says that the issue is fixed for them in AGP 7.0.0-alpha02. Unfortunately I'm getting these crashes when using AGP 7.0.0-alph04.